# Иконка в Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, icon

Хотел бы в свою программу добавить иконку, чтоб потом нажимая на нее открывалась руководство.После того как скачал, надо иконку button'а изменить, я правильно понял?

Привел как пример иконку в windows:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно самому такую иконку сделать в векторном редакторе. Если делать лень, можно просто ввести в строку поиска google 'icon help' потом перейти на вкладку 'картинки'. PROFIT!!!

Comment: Есть такая штука - гугль называется, короче вот https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=RX1&biw=1920&bih=984&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=NJxrXIzDMcWNmwWMob-oDw&q=help+icon&oq=help+icon&gs_l=img.3..0j0i67j0i7i30l8.40097.40743..41345...0.0..0.167.412.2j2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i19j0i7i30i19j0i7i10i30.hj45g8ptdC0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иконку находите в интернете или создаете в векторном редакторе.

Затем используйте `QToolButton` для создания кнопки. Для него можно задать свойство `icon`, используя при этом внешний файл либо ресурс (*.qrc). При этом, если Вы задаете `icon`, то надпись на самой кнопке будет игнорироваться.